# How do I set the initial focus on buttons in a view controller running on tvOS (AppleTV)?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, apple-tv, tvos

I've added some buttons in a Swift game for tvOS.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let button1=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(330, 800, 300, 100))
    button1(imageBuySelected, forState: UIControlState.Focused)
    button1(imageBuyNormal, forState: UIControlState.Normal
    button1 = UIColor.clearColor()
    button1(self, action: "buy1", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
    self.view!.addSubview(button1)

    let button2=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(330, 800, 300, 100))
    button2(imageBuySelected, forState: UIControlState.Focused)
    button2(imageBuyNormal, forState: UIControlState.Normal
    button2 = UIColor.clearColor()
    button2(self, action: "buy2", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
    self.view!.addSubview(button2)

    let button3=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(330, 800, 300, 100))
    button3(imageBuySelected, forState: UIControlState.Focused)
    button3(imageBuyNormal, forState: UIControlState.Normal
    button3 = UIColor.clearColor()
    button3(self, action: "playGame", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
    self.view!.addSubview(button3)
}
```

When the games starts. The initial focus is set to button1. I want the focus to be set to button3. I understand that the preferred focus is automatically selected based on the first focusable object found starting from the upper left corner of the screen. Does anyone know how override this so I can make button3 the preferredfocusview when the game starts?

Answer (score 8):

I hope this is what you were looking for, good luck! :)

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get {
        return self.button3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your view or view controller, override the `preferredFocusedView` method to return `button3`.

You can read more about this method under the [Preferred Focus Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html) section of the documentation.

Comment: I have a similar problem but my buttons are created dynamically after a server response so I can't set my preferredFocusedView?

Comment: Have you tried setNeedsFocusUpdate? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFocusEnvironment_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIFocusEnvironment/setNeedsFocusUpdate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read through the documentation and "sort of" understand what needs to be done but am failing in execution. Any chance someone could post some sample code illustrating what needs done?

Comment: My preferredFocusedView in my view controller returns a different button, depending which ones are enabled. But preferredFocusedView was being called only once, so I tried calling setNeedsFocusUpdate on the button, but that doesn't work. You need to call it on the view controller. Perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

preferredFocusedView is Depreciated, So use below

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewTemp: UIView!
override var preferredFocusEnvironments : [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    //Condition
    return [viewTemp]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `override var preferredFocusEnvironments : [UIFocusEnvironment]`. It is an array of focus environments, ordered by priority, to which this environment prefers focus to be directed during a focus update.